# Есть ли возможность начать трансляцию youtube(и fb) со своего сайта?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Есть сайт с кабинетом , предоставляет ли ютуб(fb) возможность начать трансляцию со своего сайта используя камеру и т.п , iframe какой-то без редиректа на ютуб(fb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно документации такая возможность представлена API:
[Ссылка](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/#LiveBroadcasts)

Есть и готовые клиенты, которые формально поддерживаю данные протоколы:
[Пример](https://github.com/opentok/interactive-broadcast-js)

Comment: благодарю вас =-*